# Get signature of previously purchased item In App Billing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, in-app-billing

I'm using Xamarin Android and [Xamarin.InAppBilling](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.inappbilling) component to integrate In App Billing functionality in my app. 
Before providing users with digital content I do server-side signature verification to make sure order is legit. And the only way to get signature is immediately after the purchase in OnProductPurchased event like this:

```
_serviceConnection.BillingHandler
.OnProductPurchased += (int response, Purchase purchase, string purchaseData, string purchaseSignature) => 
                {
                    // Use purchaseSignature here!
                };
```

Official [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) says that it is possible to get signatures of owned items like this:

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
ArrayList<String> signatureList =
    ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST");
```

The problem is that `GetPurchases` method in Xamarin component returns `IList<Purchase>` and not `Bundle`. That means that if for some reason my app will fail to connect to my server immediately after purchase, there will be no way to verify signature in the future and legit (paid) user won't be able to access content that they paid for.

So is there any way to get signatures of owned (previously purchased) items using Xamarin.InAppBilling component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That response `Bundle` will return a list of Product IDs, Order Details for each Purchase, and Signatures of Each Purchase.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases

Thus you should be able to use the following method to return purchases:

`public IList<Purchase> GetPurchases(string itemType)`

You will then see inside the decompiled code that it parses the 3 items from the bundle as mentioned above:

```
IList<string> stringArrayList1;
IList<string> stringArrayList2;
IList<string> stringArrayList3;

stringArrayList1 = bundle.GetStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
stringArrayList2 = bundle.GetStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
stringArrayList3 = bundle.GetStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST");
```

However the actual method returns a `IList<Purchase>` which is Deserialized into a `Purchase` object.

As a small side note, it may be possible to make a small extension library that will parse the bundle like above for the `INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST` and extend the `Purchase` object to include any further information you need.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. I looked at decompiled code and I indeed see that component uses GetStringArrayList internally. But how can I access internal Bundle object to get the signature? And how can I make the component use a subclass of Purchase that includes all additional information that i need?

Comment: I just noticed that I can use _serviceConnection.Service.GetPurchases(...) instead of _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.GetPurchases("inapp");. The previous method returns Bundle object which is exactly what I need. Is that what you meant?

Comment: There's many ways to go about it. 1) If the component is open source (Which I don't believe it is), you could extend off of it and make that method add the respective items into the `Purchase` object. 2) You can simply extend the `Purchase` class and add another few properties you need. 3) Call the original `BillingHandler` (Non-component) and return the `Bundle` to query.

Comment: Yes, it appears that the component is not open source. Second solution seems to be appropriate, but how can I make component (without changing code) to use `MyCustomPurchase` (a subclass of `Purchase` with additional properties) when deserializing json string?

Comment: You won't be able to do that. You will have to add the items to your custom object after the fact until either the component is open source or you roll your own component.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I think I will first call components `GetPurchases`, because it does on-device signature verification and raises appropriate events. And then I will call `GetPurchases` of the original `BillingHandler` and query returned Bundle for more information.